# Locale-dependent time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am looking for a way to tell in a JavaScript if user's locale prefers display of time in 12 hour AM/PM or in 24 hour clock

is there any simple way to do this or I have to struggle with navigator object and lots of cases for different languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the the toLocaleTimeString() function of the JS Date Object

[Here is a description of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)

To answer your Comment:

You can also use single methods to get the local time of the browser:

```
var date = new Date();
date.getHours();
date.getMinutes();
date.getSeconds();
```

to construct your own timestring or build a Helper around the toLocalTimeString() which formats the result if necessary. I hope this helps

Comment: There's ann issue on Safari/Mac, I'm getting 11:59:25 GMT+01:00 instead of just 11:59:25. Any workaround on that?

Comment: @pawlik I've edited the post to hopefully answer your question.